# jQuery Window Load in iOS 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

I recently updated my phone to iOS 8 and now I am experiencing really unusual behavior.

Here is a demo of the problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("A");
jQuery(window).load(function(){
    alert("B"); 
});
</script>
```

In Safari iOS 7, this brings up the dialog boxes "A" and "B". But when viewed in Safari iOS 8, only dialog box "A" shows up.

Any ideas on why window load would not be working in iOS 8?

Comment: see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32203566/736967

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a real solution for this, but if you have any  or  in your page, **Safari on iOs8** do not trigger the load event.

So you have at least 2 solutions:

- count your externals files like images, css, scripts and attach a
  **load** event on them and wait for the **last .load** of those files
- write your tag video/audio after the load events

**//EDIT:**
So I write this that helped me to still use video:

```
var $video = $('.player');
$video.each(function(){
    this.outerHTML = this.outerHTML.replace('div', 'video')
});
$video = $('.player');
```

See *Browser compatibility* here to see if **outerHTML** fits with your compatibility https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.onload = function(){ };` on the behalf of `jQuery(window).load(function(){ });` I am able to fix this issue on my project.